# Generate a lot of random strings

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, random

I have a method that will generate 50,000 *random* strings, save them all to a file, and then run through the file, and delete all duplicates of the strings that occur. Out of those 50,000 random strings, after using `set()` to generate unique ones, on average 63 of them are left.

Function to generate the strings:

```
def random_strings(size=8, chars=string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits + string.ascii_lowercase):
    return ''.join(random.choice(chars) for _ in xrange(size))
```

Delete duplicates:

```
    with open("dicts/temp_dict.txt", "a+") as data:
        created = 0
        while created != 50000:
            string = random_strings()
            data.write(string + "\n")
            created += 1
            sys.stdout.write("\rCreating password: {} out of 50000".format(created))
            sys.stdout.flush()

        print "\nRemoving duplicates.."
        with open("dicts\\rainbow-dict.txt", "a+") as rewrite:
            rewrite.writelines(set(data))
```

Example of before and after:
https://gist.github.com/Ekultek/a760912b40cb32de5f5b3d2fc580b99f

How can I generate completely random unique strings without duplicates?

Comment: Do you require 2 files or do you just want 50000 unique strings?

Comment: What is `set(data)` supposed to do?

Comment: @SimonBlack 50k unique stings

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use *set* from the start

```
created = set()
while len(created) < 50000:
    created.add(random_strings())
```

And save once outside the loop

Comment: Wouldn't this slow down this process a whole lot though?

Comment: @Pyth0nicPenguin, less than re-writing files. And if you remove doubles after you created 50k words - you get less words.

Comment: BTW, if you worry ab.execution time - you probably shouldn't log every 50k combinations.

Comment: I'm not to worried about the execution time, I was just curious as to why I was only getting 63 out of 50k is all, I'll give this a shot and see what happens, thank you

Comment: @Pyth0nicPenguin, probably because you get too many repetitions. _random_ is not as random as advertised :-) . And you are welcome

Answer (score 0):

You could guarantee unique strings by generating unique numbers, starting with a random number is a range that is 1/50000<sup>th</sup> of the total number of possibilities (62<sup>8</sup>). Then generate more random numbers, each time determining the window in which the next number can be selected. This is not *perfectly* random, but I believe it's practically close enough.

Then these numbers can each be converted to strings by considering a representation of a 62-base number. Here is the code, and a test at the end to check that indeed all 50000 strings are unique:

```
import string
import random

def random_strings(count, size=8, chars=string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits + string.ascii_lowercase):
    max = len(chars) ** size - 1
    start = 0
    choices = []
    for i in range(0,count):
        start = random.randint(start, start + (max-start) // (count-i))
        digits = []
        temp = start
        while len(digits) < size:
            temp, i = divmod(temp, len(chars))
            digits.append(chars[i])
        choices.append(''.join(digits))
        start += 1
    return choices

choices = random_strings(50000)
# optional shuffle, since they are produced in order of `chars`
random.shuffle(choices)
# Test: output how many distinct values there are:
print (len(set(choices)))
```

See it run on [repl.it](https://repl.it/Dz1g/2)

This produces your strings in linear time. With the above parameters you'll have the answer within a second on the average PC.